# .Net .Config, really long text

Tags: .net

I'm building a very simple application .net Console Application that will execute a SQL statement and post it to a URL.   My issue is that the SQL Statement Might be very long and will certainly go over many lines.   How can you specify a lot of text inside of a .config file?

Example:

```
<add key="SelectStatement" value="select * from test1table"/>
```

The above is  pretty easy and works well.   However, when that SQL is 1000+ characters long and includes many case statements, joins, group by it becomes more troublesome.  A basic copy and paste from Query Analyzer doesnt work very well.

Ideal would be below, but doesn't work.  :

```
<add key="SelectStatement"> select * from test1table </add>
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Based on the feedback, going to be more specific.

The plan is for a friend of mine, that's not too technical, to be able to deploy the .exe at various client locations.  Each location will have a similar query, but each may be different.  He'll have read only access to the tables, ie;, can't save anything into the database or create different objects.  My hope was to leave all config settings to just 1 file.  Is there a clean/easy way to store it in the .config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could also store your actual SQL statements in a database table, e.g. "SQLStatements", and then just simply define the "key" name here and grab the long text from the database.

Or you could include a text file with SQL statement in your project and mark it as "embededded resource" and store just its file name in the config.

To make things short: don't store more than a few hundred characters in config - it's just really not made for that. Store a pointer (file name, database key name etc.) in the config and the actual text (SQL statement or whatever) somewhere else.

Marc

Comment: Approved because of "To make things short: don't store more than a few hundred characters in config - it's just really not made for that"

That's really the answer I was looking for, though other responses were similar and valid.

Answer (score 4):

You could store the name of a file in your config and put the SQL into that file. Then read the file contents using [File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sql server or mySql version 5, you should turn the long sql statement into a stored procedure.  You'll have a performance gain from doing this as well.

Comment: At least on SQL Server 2000 and up, you don't really get any performance gains from stored procs anymore

Comment: Well... it does allow the database engine to cache the data execution plan for subsequent runs.  That saves a few clock cycles.  It's not necessarily enough to make design decisions, but it can add up under heavy use.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a similar system to store SQL queries within an XML document.  I added an all the queries to one file under the following or similar structure:

```
<queries>
  <query id="someQueryName" orderBy="created desc">
     select * from some table where id &lt; 500
  </query>
.....  all the other queries
</queries>
```

And then i could just pull out the query using xmlPaths or something,  the &lt and &gt are automatically translated to < and >.  I used it extensively within a few big projects with no problems and it was a great way to make slight changes to how the application worked without recompiling any code.

Comment: I +1 because I think this is what he is looking for, but it doesn't seem like a wise choice in general.

Comment: @David - Any particular issues with it?  I can elaborate further on why i used this method and explain the reasons i chose it.

Comment: I see the wisdom in your choice but it doesn't really fulfill the requirement.  I edited my post above, but I'm really looking for simplicity.  And because of its purpose I only need 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces by their XML equivalent, or better, change the setting programmatically with your long text.

Answer (score 0):

Save your overly-long query as a View in your database, and then just save `SELECT * FROM yourView` in your config file.